Problem with correct executing of 2 JavaScript functions
I have a container (with a background image) and inside this container there is some text (chosen by reading value from a text input). To fit the text I'm using textFit script. User can also choose the font and there is the major problem.
font-size
I'm putting a snippet here so you can se the problem (instructions below):


const resultContainer = document.querySelector("#slide-container");
const chosenText = document.querySelector("#ChosenText");
const chosenFont = document.querySelector("#ChosenFont");
const textOnPicture = document.querySelector(".textOnPicture");

function refreshPicture() {
  textOnPicture.textContent = chosenText.value;
  textFit(resultContainer);
}

/*function reloadPicture(manualChoose) { //function is called by pressing "Reload" button which doesn't exist in this snippet. It's unused here; I put it just for reference
  changeFontFamily(manualChoose);
  refreshPicture();
}*/

function changeFontFamily(manualChoose) {
  let fontFamily;
  if (!!manualChoose) {//when triggered by changing value of input
    fontFamily = chosenFont.value;
    textOnPicture.style.setProperty("--font-family", fontFamily);
    textFit(resultContainer);
  }/* else {//when triggered by "Reload" button, then random picture, font and color are chosen, in this snippet it is unused
    fontFamily = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)].name;//random font from an array where I have all of my fonts. 
    textOnPicture.style.setProperty("--font-family", fontFamily);
    chosenFont.value = fontFamily;
  }*/
}

function resizePicture() {
  resultContainer.style.height = resultContainer.offsetWidth * (screen.height / screen.width) + "px";
}

window.onresize = (e) => {
  resizePicture();
  textFit(resultContainer);
};

(async () => {
  resizePicture();
})();
.textOnPicture {
    font-family: var(--font-family);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0.2em;
}

#slide-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amita:wght@400;700&family=Averia+Serif+Libre:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Madimi+One&family=Underdog&family=VT323&family=Victor+Mono:ital,wght@0,100..700;1,100..700&family=Ysabeau+SC:wght@1..1000&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="text" id="ChosenText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type text here" oninput="refreshPicture()">

<select id="ChosenFont" onchange="changeFontFamily(true)">
  <option value="Amita">Amita</option>
  <option value="Averia Serif Libre">Averia Serif Libre</option>
  <option value="Victor Mono">Victor Mono</option>
</select>

<div id="slide-container">
        <span id="textOnPicture" class="textOnPicture textFitted"></span>
</div>
<script> /*It's textFit from Github, not my own code. I changed here only few settings*/ (function(root, factory) {
  "use strict";

  // UMD shim
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser
    root.textFit = factory();
  }

}(typeof global === "object" ? global : this, function () {
  "use strict";

  var defaultSettings = {
    alignVert: false, // if true, textFit will align vertically using css tables
    alignHoriz: true, // if true, textFit will set text-align: center
    multiLine: true, // if true, textFit will not set white-space: no-wrap
    detectMultiLine: true, // disable to turn off automatic multi-line sensing
    minFontSize: 6,
    maxFontSize: 10000,
    reProcess: true, // if true, textFit will re-process already-fit nodes. Set to 'false' for better performance
    widthOnly: false, // if true, textFit will fit text to element width, regardless of text height
    alignVertWithFlexbox: true, // if true, textFit will use flexbox for vertical alignment
  };

  return function textFit(els, options) {

    if (!options) options = {};

    // Extend options.
    var settings = {};
    for(var key in defaultSettings){
      if(options.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        settings[key] = options[key];
      } else {
        settings[key] = defaultSettings[key];
      }
    }

    // Convert jQuery objects into arrays
    if (typeof els.toArray === "function") {
      els = els.toArray();
    }

    // Support passing a single el
    var elType = Object.prototype.toString.call(els);
    if (elType !== '[object Array]' && elType !== '[object NodeList]' &&
            elType !== '[object HTMLCollection]'){
      els = [els];
    }

    // Process each el we've passed.
    for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
      processItem(els[i], settings);
    }
  };

  /**
   * The meat. Given an el, make the text inside it fit its parent.
   * @param  {DOMElement} el       Child el.
   * @param  {Object} settings     Options for fit.
   */
  function processItem(el, settings){
    if (!isElement(el) || (!settings.reProcess && el.getAttribute('textFitted'))) {
      return false;
    }

    // Set textFitted attribute so we know this was processed.
    if(!settings.reProcess){
      el.setAttribute('textFitted', 1);
    }

    var innerSpan, originalHeight, originalHTML, originalWidth;
    var low, mid, high;

    // Get element data.
    originalHTML = el.innerHTML;
    originalWidth = innerWidth(el);
    originalHeight = innerHeight(el);

    // Don't process if we can't find box dimensions
    if (!originalWidth || (!settings.widthOnly && !originalHeight)) {
      if(!settings.widthOnly)
        throw new Error('Set a static height and width on the target element ' + el.outerHTML +
          ' before using textFit!');
      else
        throw new Error('Set a static width on the target element ' + el.outerHTML +
          ' before using textFit!');
    }

    // Add textFitted span inside this container.
    if (originalHTML.indexOf('textFitted') === -1) {
      innerSpan = document.createElement('span');
      innerSpan.className = 'textFitted';
      // Inline block ensure it takes on the size of its contents, even if they are enclosed
      // in other tags like <p>
      innerSpan.style['display'] = 'inline-block';
      innerSpan.innerHTML = originalHTML;
      el.innerHTML = '';
      el.appendChild(innerSpan);
    } else {
      // Reprocessing.
      innerSpan = el.querySelector('span.textFitted');
      // Remove vertical align if we're reprocessing.
      if (hasClass(innerSpan, 'textFitAlignVert')){
        innerSpan.className = innerSpan.className.replace('textFitAlignVert', '');
        innerSpan.style['height'] = '';
        el.className.replace('textFitAlignVertFlex', '');
      }
    }

    // Prepare & set alignment
    if (settings.alignHoriz) {
      el.style['text-align'] = 'center';
      innerSpan.style['text-align'] = 'center';
    }

    // Check if this string is multiple lines
    // Not guaranteed to always work if you use wonky line-heights
    var multiLine = settings.multiLine;
    if (settings.detectMultiLine && !multiLine &&
        innerSpan.getBoundingClientRect().height >= parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(innerSpan)['font-size'], 10) * 2){
      multiLine = true;
    }

    // If we're not treating this as a multiline string, don't let it wrap.
    if (!multiLine) {
      el.style['white-space'] = 'nowrap';
    }

    low = settings.minFontSize;
    high = settings.maxFontSize;

    // Binary search for highest best fit
    var size = low;
    while (low <= high) {
      mid = (high + low) >> 1;
      innerSpan.style.fontSize = mid + 'px';
      var innerSpanBoundingClientRect = innerSpan.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (
        innerSpanBoundingClientRect.width <= originalWidth 
        && (settings.widthOnly || innerSpanBoundingClientRect.height <= originalHeight)
      ) {
        size = mid;
        low = mid + 1;
      } else {
        high = mid - 1;
      }
      // await injection point
    }
    // found, updating font if differs:
    if( innerSpan.style.fontSize != size + 'px' ) innerSpan.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

    // Our height is finalized. If we are aligning vertically, set that up.
    if (settings.alignVert) {
      addStyleSheet();
      var height = innerSpan.scrollHeight;
      if (window.getComputedStyle(el)['position'] === "static"){
        el.style['position'] = 'relative';
      }
      if (!hasClass(innerSpan, "textFitAlignVert")){
        innerSpan.className = innerSpan.className + " textFitAlignVert";
      }
      innerSpan.style['height'] = height + "px";
      if (settings.alignVertWithFlexbox && !hasClass(el, "textFitAlignVertFlex")) {
        el.className = el.className + " textFitAlignVertFlex";
      }
    }
  }

  // Calculate height without padding.
  function innerHeight(el){
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().height -
      parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-top'), 10) -
      parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'), 10);
  }

  // Calculate width without padding.
  function innerWidth(el){
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().width -
      parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-left'), 10) -
      parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-right'), 10);
  }

  //Returns true if it is a DOM element
  function isElement(o){
    return (
      typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? o instanceof HTMLElement : //DOM2
      o && typeof o === "object" && o !== null && o.nodeType === 1 && typeof o.nodeName==="string"
    );
  }

  function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
  }

  // Better than a stylesheet dependency
  function addStyleSheet() {
    if (document.getElementById("textFitStyleSheet")) return;
    var style = [
      ".textFitAlignVert{",
        "position: absolute;",
        "top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;",
        "margin: auto;",
        "display: flex;",
        "justify-content: center;",
        "flex-direction: column;",
      "}",
      ".textFitAlignVertFlex{",
        "display: flex;",
      "}",
      ".textFitAlignVertFlex .textFitAlignVert{",
        "position: static;",
      "}",].join("");

    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.id = "textFitStyleSheet";
    css.innerHTML = style;
    document.body.appendChild(css);
  }
}));</script>



The problem is when I change font family (by changing  value) font size doesn't change and sometimes text is outside of the container. But when I call textFit function again; it fixes.
A step by step instruction to see a problem:

Type some text to the input, for the "best" result text element should fill the container as much as it is possible.
Change font family to different. Sometimes you should see the text is too big and it's outside of the container. Or it's too small and it could be bigger.
Change size of your browser window or type one more letter in the input. Now size of the text should be correct.

So I have 2 functions: changeFontFamily and textFit. And they should execute in the exactly same order I wrote them but it looks like they aren't. I don't know what's going on here really because I don't know how to check it so it is only my hypotesis. Font family changes but font size not, here is the problem. And due to every font family basically has its own size the text is sometimes too small or too big after change of font family and it looks terrible. Of course I would like to my text always have correct size.

I decided to rewrite the question and post it one more time.

You can just edit you question. No need for an additionel/new post

Assuming that fonts is an array, where do you define it in your code? .... This line fontFamily = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)].name; depends on it but where does fonts come from?

@GetSet In this snippet it is unused. Here I could just delete that else because you can follow my instruction with only manually choosing fonts.
In original app <option> tags are generated by dedicated JS function. I have another file where I store all of the fonts and picture paths which are randomly chosen when needed. However in example I presented here it doesn't matter because, as I said, you can still make text being too big following my instruction.

You actually do say something about random choices in your question, here "The problem is when I change font family (by pressing the button and choosing it randomly or manually by changing value)". Could you clarify what exactly isnt working briefly? And edit your question to include that clarification, thanks.

"But when I call textFit function again; it fixes" ... Meaning, an amount of time has passed allowing the DOM to render when the font family was changed, and before the text fit operation --- plausibly anyway. Try this on your text fit call window.setTimeout( function() { textFit(resultContainer); }, 1 ); ... This will force the text fit op to run on the next DOM cycle. Because it may be getting jammed up not seeing that the font-family has changed, if that makes sense.

@GetSet Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. It only causes small delay when I'm typing text. It does change nothing about wrong font size :(
